# What is the sheet they attach in passport in tax-free shop?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, paperwork, duty-free

So, I bought a laptop from Yodobashi Camera in Tokyo and since its a tax free shop, I got a discount of 8%(GST in Japan). However they attached a receipt in my passport showing the same. Why? Do I have to pay this amount when I return from Tokyo.

P. S- I'm from India, and we are allowed to bring back one laptop from abroad duty-free

Answer (score 3):

You must visit the customs office at your departure airport in Japan; they will just collect the receipts, you'll have nothing to pay.

http://tax-freeshop.jnto.go.jp/eng/shopping-guide.php

> 4. Go through the procedure at the airport
>
> Submit the Proof of Tax-Free Purchase attached to your passport when leaving the country

(Reminder: customs ≠ immigration.)